# Bidirectional Association In JPA Repository Not Working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Here are my tables:

**ORDER**

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAILS (
       ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
     , ORDER_ID VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
     , ADDRESS_ID  INT 
--     , DRIVER_ID  INT 
     , BARCODE_ID  INT
     , CUSTOMER_ID  VARCHAR(60) 
     , CUSTOMER_PIN  VARCHAR(60) 
     , UNIQUE UQ_ORDER_ID_1 (ORDER_ID)
, FOREIGN KEY(BARCODE_ID) REFERENCES public.BARCODE(ID)
     , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

AND **BARCODE**

```
CREATE TABLE BARCODE (
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 , BARCODE_DETAILS VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
 , DRIVER_ID  INT 
 , VERSION INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , UNIQUE UQ_BARCODE_ID_1 (BARCODE_DETAILS)
 , PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Order to Barcode is Many To One Relationship i.e. Many Order Can Have One barcode

Here Are My repositories

**OrderRepository**

```
package com.eppvd.application.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.eppvd.application.domain.Address;
import com.eppvd.application.domain.Customer;
import com.eppvd.application.domain.Driver;
import com.eppvd.application.domain.Order;

public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    Order findByOrderId(String orderId);
//  Order findByBarcode(String barcode);
    Order findByCustomerPin(String customerPin);

//  Order findByDriver(Driver driver);
    Order findByAddress(Address address);
    Order findByCustomer(Customer customer);

}
```

And **BarcodeRepository**

```
package com.eppvd.application.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.eppvd.application.domain.Barcode;


public interface BarcodeRepository extends JpaRepository<Barcode, Long> {

    Barcode findByBarcode(String barcode);
}
```

Here Are My ServiceImpls

**OrderServiceImpl**

```
package com.eppvd.application.service.jpa;
/** imports **/

@Service("OrderService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    /** Other Methods **/

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    public Order save(Order order) {
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush(){
        orderRepository.flush();
    }

}
```

And **BarcodeServiceImpl**

```
package com.eppvd.application.service.jpa;
@Service(value="barcodeService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class BarcodeServiceImpl implements BarcodeService{

    @Autowired
    BarcodeRepository barcodeRepository;
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false)
    public Barcode save(Barcode barcode) {

        return barcodeRepository.save(barcode);
    }

}
```

And Entities

```
package com.eppvd.application.domain;
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private Barcode barcode;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="BARCODE_ID")
    public Barcode getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }   
    public void setBarcode(Barcode barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
}

package com.eppvd.application.domain;


@Entity
@Table(name = "barcode")
public class Barcode implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 3202943305655732979L;
private Long id;
private int version;
private String barcode_details;
private Set<Order> orders ;

@Column(name="BARCODE_DETAILS")
public String getBarcodeDetails() {
    return barcodeDetails;
}

public void setBarcodeDetails(String barcode) {
    this.barcodeDetails = barcode;
}

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="barcode",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Order> getOrders() {
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}
```

}

and application Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
<!--         <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>     -->
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>        
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eppvd.application.domain"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>             
            </props>        
        </property>
    </bean>    

    <context:annotation-config/>    

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.eppvd.application.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>  

<!--      <bean id="customerService" class="com.eppvd.application.service.jpa.CustomerServiceImpl"> -->
<!--  </bean>   -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eppvd.application.service.jpa"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

And JUNit Test

```
package com.eppvd.application.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:datasource-tx-jpa.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    private BarcodeService barcodeService;

    @Before
    public void createAddressCustomerDriver(){

        Barcode barcode = new Barcode();
        barcode.setBarcodeDetails("1234");
        barcodeService.save(barcode);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateOrder() {
        Barcode barcode = barcodeService.findByBarcode("1234");

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderId("OD001");
        order.setBarcode(barcode);
        order.setCustomerPin("1234");
        order.setCustomer(customerService.findByFirstName("Abhijit"));
        order.setAddress(addressService.findByStreet("BTM Layout"));



        orderService.save(order);
        orderService.flush();
        Set<Order> orders = barcode.getOrders();
assertEquals("1234", orderService.findByOrderId("OD001").getBarcode().getBarcodeDetails()); /**Works **/
        assertEquals(1, orders.size()); /**FAILS **/

    }
}
```

I tried To be as detailed as possible. So it became a bit long. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to figure out everything logically but not too sure what am I missing.There is little documentation around this area

Comment: I see no foreign key relationships to anything in the database...Also, why does the barcode own the relationship?  What is the reasoning for allowing many orders to correspond to one order?  That alone may cause much pain when querying.  My gut says that they're one-to-one and not many-to-one, but I don't know the requirements for your project...

Comment: Hi Makato here indeed one barcode can have multiple orders as the barcode is related to the delivery. A delivery can have multiple orders so this is  one to many from barcode to order. Do i need to explictly mention foreign key? Let me check on that. Other than that do you see any other issues?

Comment: Hi, Makoto I added the foreign key constarint still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an Order, and initialized its barcode. But you never added the order to the set of orders of the barcode. So its set of barcodes is empty. That's expected.

You're supposed to maintain the two sides of an association if you expect them to be coherent.

Comment: But In case of Bi Directional mapping we dont need to explicitly do so

Comment: Bidirectional associations are the only ones that can have incoherent sides. And yes, you have to do this (as your test shows).

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit what do you mean by "Bidirectional associations are the only ones that can have incoherent sides.". Is it different from the way Native Hibernate Bi Directional Works?

Comment: In a unidirectional association, there is only one side. So it's impossible to have one side not coherent with the other side, since there is no other side. So this problem of incoherent sides can only appear in bidirectional associations.

Comment: Sorry:) Probably I am a dumbo. Still I did not get it. Can you please let me know in terms with my code what is the difference between two unidirectional and one bidirectional. Anyway thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. In hibernate do we need to explicitly update?